# convert image to embroidery formate in php or java or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is any simple or any other way to convert simple image to `embroidery` formate  like (in image below) in PHP or Java or jQuery ? :

[image]

[image]

Or any service tools available or any API is there ?

I make a website for a printer company they provided all printing items and the also provided t-shirt `embroidery` printing.

So I must give up them to online t-sirt demo of `embroidered` t-shirt.

I search tools for it from a day but not success yet..

Comment: AFAIK , there's nothing like that in javaScript/jQuery.

Comment: I’d start by searching for how an effect like this is done _algorithmically_ … if you find one that’s not too complex, you could implement it in either JS using canvas or PHP using GDlib.

Comment: this is a question for Google, not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435384/how-to-create-a-dst-embroidery-file-using-java

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the open source project [Embroidermodder](http://embroidermodder.github.io), as part of this application we will soon be working on bitmap to embroidery. It is a complex process, we have the preliminary work done for generating stitches from an outline. In our next major release we should be capable of doing something like this.